how to use custom preview function for fzf command on zsh
foo() {
    echo "bar"
}
export -f foo

fzf --preview "foo"

leads to opened preview window and error msg:
zsh:1: command not found: foo

How can I define my custom function that can be used for generating the preview?

You have to export your function: export -f foo!

thanks for the reply, but check the code again, it's exported

[tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] are two differents tools!! This all work under [tag:bash], not [tag:zsh]!

thanks, that's the issue.. in zsh the export -f doens't work, thx

If so, feel free to upvote my comment (and maybe close/delete the question)

To try: put the foo function in ~/.zshenv, and also add this line: export SHELL=zsh. According to this man page, fzf uses the SHELL variable when executing commands. I don't have fzf installed, so you'll have to let us know if it works.

found (ugly) workaround for zsh:

put all the functions that should be called from --preview to its own file - let's call this preview_functions.sh

preview_functions.sh:
foo() {
    echo "bar"
}


use it in the following way:

fzf --preview "source preview_functions.sh && foo"

..pretty ugly, but now I am getting the bar in the preview. Thanks F. Hauri for pointing me to a right direction, zsh != bash
This alsow works - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406781/26894 but I don't want to mess my .zshenv

But from there, you have no advantage of running this as a function over simply running this as a script, ( by replacing foo() {  by a shebang at 1st line... and drop last curly brace } at last line. )

If really, you could do something like: sfoo="$(declare -f foo)";sfoo=${sfoo#*\{} sfoo=${sfoo%$'\n\}'};fzf --preview "zsh <(echo '${sfoo%\}}') {}"  (Feel free to replace zsh with bash! I've tested this with a more complex function, this work under [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh]!)
